# Explain the relation between lead, account, opportunity, and contact

Tags: visualforce

What is the relation between leads, accounts, opportunities, and contacts? Please can any one explain the major relationships between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Data Model documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm), specifically the [Sales Objects ERD](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm). It depicts the relationships among those standard objects.

[image]